# LUKS discard/TRIM: conflicting kernel command line options

Tags: luks, dm-crypt, cryptsetup, kernel-parameters

I'm confused between the various ways that `LUKS`/`dmcrypt`/`cryptsetup` discard /TRIM operations can be enabled via the Linux kernel command line.

1. The [`dracut` manpage](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/dracut.cmdline.7.html):

   > `rd.luks.allow-discards`
   >
   > Allow using of discards (TRIM) requests on all LUKS partitions.
2. The [`systemd-cryptsetup-generator` manpage](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd-cryptsetup-generator.html#luks.options=)

   > `luks.options=, rd.luks.options=`
   >
   > ... If only a list of options, without an UUID, is specified, they apply to any UUIDs not specified elsewhere, and without an entry in /etc/crypttab. ...

   The argument `rd.luks.options=discard` is recommended [here](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Dm-crypt/Specialties#Discard.2FTRIM_support_for_solid_state_drives_.28SSD.29).
3. The [Arch wiki section on LUKS and SSDs](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Dm-crypt/Specialties#Discard.2FTRIM_support_for_solid_state_drives_.28SSD.29)  shows a third colon-seprated field:

   > `cryptdevice=/dev/sdaX:root:allow-discards`

Questions:

1. What is the difference between `discard` and `allow-discards`? Is the former mandatory and the second optional?
2. Will `luks.options=` or `rd.luks.options=` apply given `cryptdevice=/dev/sda2` (eg not a UUID)? What if `cryptdevice=` is given a UUID, does that count as "specified elsewhere"?
3. Will `luks.options=` or `rd.luks.options=` overwrite / append / prepend if `cryptsetup=` already gives options?
4. Is there any disadvantage to using `rd.luks.allow-discards` which seems to be simplest if TRIM is wanted everywhere?

Comment: Should `cryptsetup=` read `cryptdevice=` instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends a little on the distribution you are using and what components are included by dracut in the initramfs.

For example, the `cryptdevice=` option is interpreted by the [encrypt hook](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Dm-crypt/Specialties#The_encrypt_hook_and_multiple_disks). Thus, it's only relevant for initramfs images that include this hook.

The disadvantage of `rd.luks.allow-discards` and `rd.luks.allow-discards=` is that it simply doesn't work. The `dracut.cmdline(7)` description of these options is incorrect. I tested it under Fedora 26 where it doesn't work and there is even a [bug report for Fedora 19](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=890533#c40) where this deviation between documented and actual behavior was discussed and it was closed as wont-fix.

The `luks.options=` and `rd.luks.options=` are more generic as you basically can place any valid crypttab option in there, e.g. `discard`. Since they are interpreted by `systemd-cryptsetup-generator` which doesn't care about `cryptdevice=` you can't expect a useful interaction between these options.

Note that `luks.options=` only has an effect for devices that **aren't** listed in the initramfs image's `etc/crypttab` file.

Thus,  to enable dm-crypt pass-though SSD trim support (a.k.a. discard) for dm-crypted devices opened during boot you have 2 options:

1. add `rd.luks.options=discard` to the kernel command line and make sure that the initramfs image doesn't include a `etc/crypttab`
2. add the discard option to the relevant entries in `/etc/crypttab` and make sure that the current version is included in the initramfs image.

You can use `lsinitrd /path/to/initramfs etc/crypttab` for checking the initramfs image, `dracut -v -f /path/to/initramfs-image` for regenerating the image after changes to `/etc` and `dmsetup table` to see whether the crypted device was actually opened with the discard option (the relevant entries should include the string `allow_discards` then).

Answer (score 0):

NecroAnswering to question:
What is the difference between discard and allow-discards?

AFAIK:
DISCARD is readed by "mount" command, so it can be put on fstab and crypttab, as *mount* option

ALLOW-DISCARDS is readed by "cryptsetup" command, so it has no place in fstab or cripttab file.
  There is more, but that is for You, dear reader, to find out.